# How to center :after in a div?

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a project in which I am using some divs, and the `:after` pseudo-element. I would like to be able to center the `:after` text inside the div. Can anybody help me out here?

Example of problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnFish/7ra5t/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just have to add a `text-align: center` in your CSS:

```
.example {
    background: black;
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center
}
.example:after {
    content: "+";
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

If you also want vertical alignment:

```
.example {
    background: black;
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.example:after {
    content: "+";
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Did you want vertical alignment too?

Comment: Won't that apply text-align: center to the .example content as well?

Comment: Yes, it will, but there was no text in the example div in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it:

```
.example { ... position: relative; }
.example:after { ...
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; margin-top: -{50% of the element's height}; 
  left: 50%; margin-left: -{50% of the element's width};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with flex

```
.example {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will center the overlay on a media element. The CSS includes some extra properties to demonstrate related issues when trying to center overlays.

Notes:

- Elements such as `video` and `image` do not support `:before` or `:after` directly. They need a wrapper.

  - Set these elements to `display: block` to avoid unexpected inline related line-height issues when trying to center other elements on top.
- The overlay needs to be positioned absolutely relative to the wrapper.
- `:after` shows up on top of the wrapped element, and can display backgrounds on the overlay.
- `inset` is shorthand for `top right bottom left`.
- `inset` set to `auto` for the trailing bits prevents stretching backgrounds.
- `translate` shifts the entire element, including the trailing bits.
- `content` accepts `attr()` references to element properties to grab the text content. This pairs well with programmatic setting of `data` properties in the HTML code.

```css
.pics {
  display: flex;
  gap: .5em;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  /* can ignore items below this line */
  border-radius: .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper:after {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 50% auto auto 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  content: attr(data-overlay);
  /* can ignore items below this line */
  background-color: white;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  opacity: .8;
  border-radius: .5em;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 black;
}
```

```html
<div class="pics">
  <div class="wrapper" data-overlay="Overlay 1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Pic 1" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" data-overlay="Overlay 2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Pic 2" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" data-overlay="Overlay 3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Pic 3" />
  </div>
</div>
```